# Training tricks for increasing stability in mixed precision

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, training, pytorch

I would love to be able to use automatic mixed precision more extensively in my training, but I find that it is too unstable and often ends in NaNs. Are there any general tricks in training that people here have used to improve stability?

I've seen the following general tips:

- plot the gradients and force unstable layers to fp32
- bump weight decay in the optimizer
- bump epsilon in the optimizer
- add/try different normalization layers
- force loss calculations to fp32

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are several techniques that can help improve the stability of training with automatic mixed precision in TensorFlow or PyTorch. Some common strategies include:

- **Using a lower learning rate**: When using mixed precision, the gradient values can be more sensitive to the learning rate. Using a lower learning rate can help to reduce the chance of encountering NaN values in the gradients.
- **Gradient clipping**: Gradient clipping is a technique where the gradients are scaled down if they exceed a certain threshold. This can help to prevent large gradients from causing instability in the training process.
- **Weight decay**: Weight decay is a regularization technique that applies a penalty to the weights in the model, forcing them to be small and preventing them from growing too large. This can help to improve the stability of training with mixed precision.
- **Careful initialization of weights**: The initial values of the weights in a model can have a big impact on the stability of training. Carefully choosing the initial values of the weights can help to prevent instability and improve the convergence of the training process.

**Initialization of weights:**
There are a few different approaches that you can use to find good initial weights for your model. One approach is to initialize the weights randomly using a **Gaussian distribution** with a **mean of zero** and a **standard deviation** that is calculated based on the number of inputs to the layer. This can help to ensure that ***the weights are not too large or too small***, which can help to stabilize the training process.

Another approach is to use a method called **Xavier initialization**, which is named after its creator, ***Xavier Glorot***. This method initializes the weights using a **Gaussian distribution** with a ***standard deviation calculated based on the number of inputs and outputs to the layer***. This can help to ensure that the weights are not too large or too small, which can improve the convergence of the training process.

Ultimately, the best approach will depend on the specific characteristics of your model and your training data. It may be necessary to experiment with **different weight initialization methods** to find the one that works best for your particular use case.

In **TensorFlow**, you can use the automatic mixed precision training utility to enable mixed precision training and take advantage of these techniques. In **PyTorch**, you can use the native support for mixed precision training to enable it and use these techniques to improve stability.

In general, it's important to experiment and find the right combination of hyperparameters and techniques that work best for your specific model and dataset.

Comment: How would you go about finding good weight initializations? Trial and error?

Comment: random initialization method, such as using a random uniform distribution or a Gaussian distribution with a small standard deviation or a Xavier or He initialization method or using a combination of these methods and fine-tuning the initial weights through trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

I find myself following these strategies

- Use a small value for the gradient scaling factor, which can help prevent the gradients from becoming too small or too large.
- Carefully choose the data types used for the various parameters and activations in the network, and make sure that they are compatible with each other.
- Use a well-tuned optimizer
- Of course, monitor the training process carefully and make sure that the gradients are not becoming too small or too large. If the gradients are getting too small, this can cause the training process to converge slowly or even stop altogether, so it's important to catch this issue and adjust the gradient scaling factor or data types as needed.